# Segmentation fault while running Java program on Linux

Tags: java, linux

I am running a JAVA program on RHEL 6.4 Server. The program terminates abnormally displaying the messaeg "Segmentation fault(Core dumped)". But i do not find any file indicating the reason for termination in the current user directory from where the program was run.

How can i debug to find the error in such case?

**DOUBT**

As per my understandin segmentation fault occurs when program tries to access a memory address outside the programs range. I would expect to see such faults in C or C++ programs, but in Java since there are no pointers , how is segmentation fault possible.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the core dump in `gdb`?

Comment: What version and build of java are you using? As it can be in JVM? Do you use any native lib?

Comment: A segfault indicates an error in some native code (do you use a native library) or in the JVM itself. Some JVMs put the log file about the problem in the home directory.

Comment: @KepaniHaole, i am not aware about gdb, can you please give an overview on how to debug with it. Where will i find a core file generated after the fault.

Comment: I am not using any native code... just plain JDBC with bouncycastle on JDK 1.6.. but deals with large number of rows..

Answer (score 3):

> how is segmentation fault possible.

There are several possible reasons for this. There could be a bug in the JVM itself, or in a package (some of these are written in C or C++). It could also be due to a misconfiguration where incompatible components are used together.

From experience, a JVM bug is the least likely of these (although I've seen some).

If you capture the stack trace at the point of the crash, this might give you some clues as to where exactly the crash is occurring.

Comment: I do not get any stacktrace, i just see the message that segmentation fault occured.

Comment: but you do get a core dump file and there are tools to read such